# No change in the front office in Prestashop in my first module

Tags: php, css, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

**First day on PrestaShop**. Using PrestaShop 1.6 from the PrestaShop tutorial: [Creating a PrestaShop Module](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+PrestaShop+Module) I have created a module(`mymodule`).

But I don't see anything special in the front office. **My module** is listed in the modules' list. Installed and followed the tutorial. But still there's no change in the front(cache also cleared).

**\css\mymodule.css**

```
div#mymodule_block_home p {
  font-size: 150%;
  font-style:italic;
}
```

**\views\templates\hook\mymodule.tpl**

```
<!-- Block mymodule -->
<div id="mymodule_block_home" class="block">
  <h4>Welcome!</h4>
  <div class="block_content">
    <p>Hello,
       {if isset($my_module_name) && $my_module_name}
           {$my_module_name}
       {else}
           World
       {/if}
       !       
    </p>   
    <ul>
      <li><a href="{$my_module_link}" title="Click this link">Click me!</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /Block mymodule -->
```

**\mymodule.php**

```
<?php   
/*This checks for the existence of an always-existing PrestaShop constant (its version number), and if it does not exist, it stops the module from loading. The sole purpose of this is to prevent malicious visitors to load this file directly.*/
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
  exit;

class MyModule extends Module
{  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->name = 'mymodule';
    $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
    $this->version = '1.0.0';
    $this->author = 'Firstname Lastname';
    $this->need_instance = 0;
    $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_); 
    $this->bootstrap = true;
 
    parent::__construct();
 
    $this->displayName = $this->l('My module');
    $this->description = $this->l('Description of my module.');
 
    $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');
 
    if (!Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME'))      
      $this->warning = $this->l('No name provided');
  }
 
  public function install()
  {   if (Shop::isFeatureActive())
        Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_ALL);

      return parent::install() &&
      $this->registerHook('leftColumn') &&
      $this->registerHook('header') &&
      Configuration::updateValue('MYMODULE_NAME', 'my friend');
  }
   
  public function uninstall()
  {
      if (!parent::uninstall() ||
        !Configuration::deleteByName('MYMODULE_NAME')
      )
        return false;

      return true;
  }
 
  public function getContent()
  {
    $output = null;
 
    if (Tools::isSubmit('submit'.$this->name))
    {
        $my_module_name = strval(Tools::getValue('MYMODULE_NAME'));
        if (!$my_module_name
          || empty($my_module_name)
          || !Validate::isGenericName($my_module_name))
            $output .= $this->displayError($this->l('Invalid Configuration value'));
        else
        {
            Configuration::updateValue('MYMODULE_NAME', $my_module_name);
            $output .= $this->displayConfirmation($this->l('Settings updated'));
        }
    }
    return $output.$this->displayForm();
  }
  public function displayForm()
  {
    // Get default language
    $default_lang = (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');
     
    // Init Fields form array
    $fields_form[0]['form'] = array(
        'legend' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Settings'),
        ),
        'input' => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => $this->l('Configuration value'),
                'name' => 'MYMODULE_NAME',
                'size' => 20,
                'required' => true
            )
        ),
        'submit' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Save'),
            'class' => 'button'
        )
    );
     
    $helper = new HelperForm();
     
    // Module, token and currentIndex
    $helper->module = $this;
    $helper->name_controller = $this->name;
    $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
    $helper->currentIndex = AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name;
     
    // Language
    $helper->default_form_language = $default_lang;
    $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = $default_lang;
     
    // Title and toolbar
    $helper->title = $this->displayName;
    $helper->show_toolbar = true;        // false -> remove toolbar
    $helper->toolbar_scroll = true;      // yes - > Toolbar is always visible on the top of the screen.
    $helper->submit_action = 'submit'.$this->name;
    $helper->toolbar_btn = array(
        'save' =>
        array(
            'desc' => $this->l('Save'),
            'href' => AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name.'&save'.$this->name.
            '&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
        ),
        'back' => array(
            'href' => AdminController::$currentIndex.'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
            'desc' => $this->l('Back to list')
        )
    );
     
    // Load current value
    $helper->fields_value['MYMODULE_NAME'] = Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME');
     
    return $helper->generateForm($fields_form);
  }
  public function hookDisplayLeftColumn($params)
  {
    $this->context->smarty->assign(
      array(
          'my_module_name' => Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME'),
          'my_module_link' => $this->context->link->getModuleLink('mymodule', 'display')
      )
  );
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'mymodule.tpl');
  }
   
  public function hookDisplayRightColumn($params)
  {
    return $this->hookDisplayLeftColumn($params);
  }
   
  public function hookDisplayHeader()
  {
    $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'css/mymodule.css', 'all');
  }   
}
```

Now I can see the configure option for **My module** in the back office.
Still nothing different in the front.

Waiting for your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be due to inconsistent hooks names, you registered `leftColumn` hook, however, all hooks since 1.5 (I think) begin with either `action` or `display`. Therefore, try registerting `displayLeftColumn` and have a method `hookDisplayLeftColumn` or rename your current method to `hookLeftColumn`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. As you said, I have changed the function name from `hookDisplayLeftColumn` to `hookLeftColumn`. But still...

Comment: Try changing the hook name to `displayLeftColumn` instead of changing the fucntion.

Comment: And also reinstall the module after that.

Comment: So I changed the hook name from `leftColumn` to `displayLeftColumn`(not sure about the **hook name**). But still the same I get.

Comment: Did you reinstall module ?

Comment: Got it! The `Hello, my firend!` was there in the left column. There was no "left column" in the front page. The site displays it in the inner pages.